# mock fs.readFile with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock fs.readFile:

```
fs.readFile = jest.fn((_, callback) => callback(null, JSON.stringify('sample')));
```

I' m trying to test this function:

```
export const readFileAsynchronously = async (pathToFile: string) => {
  const fullPath = join(__dirname, pathToFile);
  if (existsSync(fullPath)) {
    const fileContent = await readFile(fullPath);
    return fileContent.toString();
  }

  return null;
};
```

And I want to test this function without reading the real file, is it possible?
The test is:

```
test('should return file content if file exists', async () => {
    jest.mock('fs');
    const existsSync = () => true;
    fs.existsSync = existsSync;
    fs.readFile = jest.fn((_, callback) => {
      return callback(null, JSON.stringify('sample'));
    });
    jest.mock('path');
    path.join = (path: string) => path;
    const pathToFile = './test.txt';
    const result = await readFileAsynchronously(pathToFile);
    expect(result).toEqual('sample');
  });
```

But I've got a type error
Property `__promisify__` is not presented in type "Mock<any, [_: any, callback: any], any>" and is required in type "typeof readFile".
I've tried one more variant:

```
   const mockedFs = fs as jest.Mocked<typeof fs>;
    const existsSync = () => true;
    fs.existsSync = existsSync;
    mockedFs.readFile.mockImplementationOnce(
      () =>
        new Promise(function (resolve) {
          return resolve('test');
        }),
    );
```

But I've got an error:

```
TypeError: mockedFs.readFile.mockImplementationOnce is not a function
```

I don't have any idea how to solve it. Please, could you help me?

Comment: You need to provide more code, how you try to test, and how you use that fn. `fs.readFile = ...` is not mocking but overrides the original function. You need to use either `jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFile')` or `jest.mock('fs')` and provide mock implementation.

Comment: You are not showing what the `callback` is. But to me, this test case does not make any sense. You are mocking everything. :|

Comment: I want to mock everything because I want to test how function implementation works   without  interaction with the actual file system

Comment: I've tried variant without callback, but it doesn't work also. I want to understand how to mock readFile

Comment: Added the answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `readFile` is not a promise. You need to use a callback or use a different function `readFileSync`.

Your function is not implemented correctly, here is the fixed version

```js
import { join } from 'path';
import { existsSync, readFile } from 'fs';
export const readFileAsynchronously = async (pathToFile: string) => {
  const fullPath = join(__dirname, pathToFile);
  if (existsSync(fullPath)) {
    // Making it to resolve when callback is invoked
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      readFile(fullPath, 'utf8', (error, fileContent) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(fileContent);
      });
    });
  }

  return Promise.reject(new Error('File not found'));
};
```

And here is your test implementation

```js
jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  existsSync: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
  readFile: jest.fn().mockImplementation((path, options, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'my file content');
  }),
}));

test('should resolve without reading the actual file', async () => {
  const result = await readFileAsynchronously('test.txt');
  expect(result).toBe('my file content');
});
```